# how to duplicate JSON file and keep it format in NSIS

Tags: json, nsis

I just want to duplicate a JSON file.
currently I'm using NsJSON for reading the JSON files.
this is my code:

```
nsJSON::Set /file $DESKTOP\nsis\a.json
nsJSON::Serialize /format /file $DESKTOP\nsis\a_new.json
```

the problem is:

```
"obj": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
```

becomes:

```
"obj": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
        ]
```

I must keep the json content with the original file format. 
How do I do that with NsJson?
If there is no way, can you recommend a different JSON parser that can do this?

Comment: So you need the whitespace to stay exactly the same?

Comment: yes, i need to keep everything exactly the same

Comment: What is the problem, the newlines or spaces/tabs? It is still legal JSON...

Comment: I know its still a legal JSON, but I need to keep it as is (for other things). so yes, the problem is the newlines and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate a file, then use the CopyFiles command.

```
CopyFiles "$DESKTOP\nsis\a.json" "$DESKTOP\nsis\a_new.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any other JSON parser plugins but IMHO your problem is that you require a specific format and not just any kind of valid JSON.

If you cannot change your JSON parser I guess you can post-process the JSON in NSIS (This code does not handle all types of quotes nor escaped quotes!):

```
Function PrettyOnelineJSON
Exch $0
Push $1
Push $2
Push $3
Push $4
StrCpy $1 "" ; In quote?
StrCpy $2 "" ; Prev. char.
StrCpy $3 "" ; Pos.
loop:
    StrCpy $4 $0 1 $3
    StrCmp $4 "" done
    IntOp $3 $3 + 1
    StrCmp $4 " " 0 +2
        StrCmp $4 $2 eatone ; Was this and the previous character a space?
    StrCpy $2 $4
    StrCmp $4 "$\n" eatone
    StrCmp $4 "$\r" eatone
    StrCmp $4 '"' 0 loop
    StrCmp $4 $1 +3
        StrCpy $1 $4
        Goto loop
    StrCpy $1 ""
    Goto loop
done:
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1
    Exch $0
    Return
eatone:
    StrCmp $1 "" 0 loop ; In a quoted string?
    StrCpy $4 $0 "" $3
    IntOp $3 $3 - 1
    StrCpy $0 $0 $3
    StrCpy $0 $0$4
    Goto loop
FunctionEnd


Section

StrCpy $0 '"obj": [$\n            "a A  a   A",$\n            "b",$\n            "c"$\n        ]'
MessageBox mb_ok ORG=|$0|

Push $0
Call PrettyOnelineJSON
Pop $0

MessageBox mb_ok NEW=|$0|

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the original file format, you should not use the /format switch.
Using it will format the output in a "pretty print" style.